# How to use correctly cps notation in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops

I am trying to write some code in Jenkins, but my knowledge is quite limited, I need to read some information (the commiter for that CL) from a xml file that Perforce generates(SCM) I then use that information I get, in another function to send an email in case the static analysis finds an error, the thing is I keep getting the  `expected to call WorkflowScript.sendEmailNewErrors but wound up catching readJSON` Error, I have gone through the CPS [documentation](https://jenkins.io/redirect/pipeline-cps-method-mismatches/) The output tells me but honestly it is still not clear to me what is wrong. My pipeline would be something like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

@NonCPS
def sendEmailNewErrors(){
        def submitter = findItemInChangelog("changeUser")
        def Emails = readJSON file: "D:/Emails.json"
        def email = "test@email.com"
        def msgList = []
        def url = "http://localhost:8080/job/job1/1374/cppcheck/new/api/json"
        def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(new URL(url).text)

        for (key in Emails.keySet()) {
            if (submitter == key){
                email = Emails.get(key)
            }
        }

        json.issues.each{issue->
            def msg = "New ERROR found in static analysis, TYPE OF ERROR ${issue.type}"+
                ", SEVERITY: ${issue.severity}, ERROR MESSAGE: ${issue.message}"+
                ", FILE ${issue.fileName} AT LINE: ${issue.lineStart}"
            msgList.add(msg)
        }
                        
        msgList.each{msg->
            println msg
            mail to: email,
            subject: "New errors found in job1 build pipeline",
            body: "$msg"
        }
    
}

@NonCPS
def findItemInChangelog(item){
    def result = "Build ran manually"
    def found = false 
    def file = new XmlSlurper().parse("C:/Users/User/.jenkins/jobs/job1/builds/1374/changelog5966810591791724161.xml")
    file.entry.each { entry ->
        entry.changenumber.each { changenumber ->
            changenumber.children().each { tag ->
                if(tag.name() == item && found != true){
                    result = tag.text()
                    found = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result.toString()
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {    
        stage("test"){
            steps{
                script{
                    sendEmailNewErrors()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried without CPS notation but I understand if using .each method the notation has to be used. Anyone with more experience with this is able to help?

Comment: What leads you to believe the error is related to the `NonCPS` annotation?

Comment: probably my lack of knowledge as I am quiet junior and I do not work with Jenkins on a daily basis at all, what is the issue in your opionion?

Comment: I just tried to change the line where I define the Emails var for 
 'def emails = [
            "person1": "email@person1.net",
            "person2": "email@person2.net",
              ....
        ]'
and that seems to work, though I want to read the information from a file not like that...